# How to call a typescript arrow function and a javascript function in the same event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I want to call both a javascript function and a typescript function from the same event. It is a onClick event in a chart. I am relatively new to typescript and angular, so i dont know if what i am doing is even possible.

The problem is: I need to call a javascript function for getting a activated bar in the chart, and the typescript function to open a dialog in the angular component.

```js
    onClick: function(evt){

      console.log(this);//<-- returns chart

      bar: () => {console.log(this)}; //<-- here I try to get this as component
      bar(); // <--doesnt work

      //console.log(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  }
```

Maybe bette if i show the whole thing.

```js
  public barChartOptions = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'],
    onHover: console.log('onHover'),

    onClick: function(evt){
      //console.log(evt); Mouse Event
      console.log(this);
      const getFirst = array => console.log(this);
      console.log(getFirst);
      //bar: () => {console.log(this)};
      //bar();
      //console.log(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  },
    /*
    onClick : (evt, datasets) => {
      //let self = this;
      //console.log(self);
      if(datasets.length > 0){
        this.openDialog();
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.barChart);
      }
    },*/
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right'
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'point'
    }
  };
```

this is my html template:

```html
  my-bar-dialog works!
  <div>
    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart
              id="myChart"
              [datasets]="barChartData"
              [labels]="barChartLabels"
              [options]="barChartOptions"
              [legend]="barChartLegend"
              [chartType]="barChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
  <button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
```

Now, the thing is i have two different "this":
1)

```js
    onClick: function(evt){
      let that = this;
      let bar=()=> {console.log(that.this)};
      bar();

  },
```

2)

```js
    onClick : (evt, datasets) => {
      if(datasets.length > 0){
        console.log(this);
      }
    },
```

1 returns a char, 2 returns the component.
But i need both of them in the same Event/function as i need to call chartjs api functions and i need to call a function from my component.

And here my component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { BarChartService } from '../bar-chart.service';
import { barChartClass } from '../barChartClass';

declare var foo: Function;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-bar-dialog',
  templateUrl: './my-bar-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-bar-dialog.component.css'],
})
export class MyBarDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  client: string;
  tenant: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private barChartService: BarChartService) {
    foo();
  }
  //First BarChart
  barChart: barChartClass;
  public barChartLabels: any;
  public barChartType: any;
  public barChartLegend: any;
  public barChartData: any;

  getBarChart(): void {
    this.barChartService.getMockBarChart().subscribe(
      barChart => this.barChart = barChart
    );
    this.barChartData = this.barChart.barChartData;
    this.barChartLabels = this.barChart.barChartLabels;
    this.barChartType = this.barChart.barChartType;
    this.barChartLegend = this.barChart.barChartLegend;
  }

  public barChartOptions = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'],
    onHover: console.log('onHover'),


    onClick: function(evt){
      //console.log(evt); Mouse Event
      //console.log(this);
      let that = this;
      //bar: () => {console.log(this)};
      let bar=()=> {console.log(that.this)};
      bar();
      //bar();
      //console.log(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  },
    /*
    onClick : (evt, datasets) => {
      //let self = this;
      //console.log(self);
      if(datasets.length > 0){
        this.openDialog();
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.barChart);
      }
    },*/
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right'
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'point'
    }
  };

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogData, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {client: this.client, tenant: this.tenant}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.client = result;
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBarChart();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-data',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-data.html',
  styleUrls: ['dialog-data.css']
})
export class DialogData {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogData>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: before accessing your function assign this to some other variable like `var that = this;` and inside your function `this` will point to chart and `that` will point to your component

Comment: Post html template with your chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before using the chart in component assign this to some other variable like

`var that=this`

then in your chart

```
 onClick: function(evt){

      console.log(this);//<-- returns chart

   let   bar= () => {console.log(that)}; //<-- that should have your component refrence

  }
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-ioywdj)

Comment: @ if you can create [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) for your application than i can show you working example

Comment: as @smytt said it should be `bar=()=>` not `bar:()=>`

Comment: a stackblitz is a bit hard to implement as i am using chartjs and the charts are created dynamically but i will try,

further i tried as you suggested and now my bar() function works but i returns the same thing as my console.log(this)

maybe i explained it bad i will edit  my post a bit.

Comment: where are using `public barChartOptions = {` in consturctor? Did you try `var that=this` before this(`public barChartOptions = {`) line? and use that inside function

Comment: @Gen0v check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-ioywdj

Comment: Ok nice thanks, i see how it is supposed to work. I guess i need to change my code.

But I tried it with my existing code now like :

```typescript
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var that=this;
  }
```

```typescript
      onClick: function(evt){
      console.log(this);
      let bar=()=> {this.that.openDialog()};
      bar();
  },
```
With this I get an undefined, is there a way to solve this ? Or do i need to change my code to work like in the example.

Thanks a lot already.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing with the bar and the colon in the function is that you're trying to describe its type rather to declare it. So if you want to actually declare the function, do this:

```
onClick: function(evt) {

    console.log(this);//<-- returns chart

    let bar = () => { console.log(this) };
    bar();

    //console.log(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  }
```

if you want to describe and declare it, do this:

```
  onClick: function(evt) {

    console.log(this);//<-- returns chart

    let bar: () => void = () => { console.log(this) }; //<-- here I try to get this as component
    bar(); // <--doesnt work

    //console.log(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  }
```